# Windows 11 got unactivated after upgrading from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

I bought Lenovo Windows laptop with Windows 10. I upgraded it to Windows 11. Few days ago, it started giving following message:

[image]

Now it says activation state: Not active.

[image]

If I recall it correct, I guess Windows used to activate automatically, if came pre-installed with laptop. What happened now?

Comment: Please run the command `Slmgr /dli` and add the screenshot of the dialog to your post. Question: How did you obtain this computer? Do you have a sticker on the computer with a Windows serial number?

Comment: Contact Microsoft Support to make sure your Windows 10 License is valid.

Comment: Register Win11 using you Win10 serial number. That worked for me.